# Computer Architecture and Design

Tags: kernel

if ax+b *c / g is input from the keyboard;trace the path of execution from the keyboard to the final output onto the printer which uses bidirectional I/O interface, using your knowledge in computer architecture design.

Can someone help me with this question?

Comment: While on Stack Overflow "homework" questions are allowed, we will **not do the homework for you**. We expect you to perform some research on the topic, and state in the question post **which exact part** of the homework is difficult for you.

Comment: The thing is i don't even know where to start from. I have been searching and still searching but all i keep getting is just information on Computer I/O. If i could even get a pointer as to where and what to look for i would be glad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So basically what i came to understand is that, most computers have 3 main ways they compute.

1.Prefix e.g. +ab

2.Infix e.g a+b

3.Postfix e.g. ab+

First the input from the keyboard (ax + b * c / g) is sent to the RAM. From the RAM it passes through the cache memory to the CPU.

The CPU contains the Control unit (CU), Arithmetic logic unit (ALU) and Internal memory and registers. The ALU basically handles computations in the CPU. Thus the computation is sent to the ALU.

So assuming the the computer uses a postfix notation to compute:

Using the memory registers, it begins the computation as follows:

a) ax + b will compute as axb+ = X1. The previous operands are cleared and replaced by the answer (X1). The computation continuous as follows:

b) X1 * C will compute as X1C* = X2

c) X2 / g will compute as X2g/ = X3.

X3 will be the final answer and is sent to the printer to be printed.

[An image showing the path of execution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pht8M.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

1. The first step, would be for your system to request data from the character device (keyboard) and take in data till your obtain the termination character i.e. \n 0x0a. You would repeat this until you have the necessary operands. The character device output would be saved into the process's memory space (unlikely to be in cache at this point, if the system uses DMA)
2. The operands are computed using the ALU and saved into memory. The result will be in cache as the memory was directly accessed by the CPU.
3. A very key part of this question is the bidirectional I/O of the printer. The result will be send for the printer to read. The printer can then report back the status of the print operation to tell the system whether the operation has been finished via the interface from the printer to the system.